# MySQL Error: #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using following code in my SQL:

```
CREATE 'tbl_login' (
  'email' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  'password' varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO 'tbl_login' ('email', 'password') VALUES
('xxx@gmail.com', 'password');
```

But following error message is being shown:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tbl_login' (
>     'email' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     'password' varchar(255) NOT NUL' at line 1

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-tables.html Also please google same things before posting a question...

Comment: `CREATE TABLE tbl_login`, And don't use straight quotes for names, use backquotes.

Comment: I sincerely hope that you will be hashing the passwords using `password_hash()` before you insert them, and _not_  storing them in plain text?

Answer (score 2):

You are giving **''** on the table name and you missed to add **TABLE**  on creating the table that's why this error is coming.

Try this on

```
CREATE TABLE  `tbl_login` (
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `tbl_login` (`email`, `password`) VALUES
('xxx@gmail.com', 'password');
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating table and inserting rows in the wrong way, use backticks instead of single quotes for table and column names. Also, one more syntax error in the form of missing `TABLE` in `CREATE ...` statement. It should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_login` ( 
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL 
);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_login` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('xxx@gmail.com', 'password');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using back ticks instead of single quotes (plus your create statement is missing `TABLE` keyword), e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_login` ( `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL ); 
INSERT INTO `tbl_login` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('xxx@gmail.com', 'password');
```

Comment: will single quotes `'` works here `'email', 'password'` may be not

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Borat,**

Try this code,

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_login(email varchar(255) NOT NULL,password varchar(255) NOT NULL); 
INSERT INTO tbl_login(email,password) VALUES('xxx@gmail.com', 'password');
```

Using php to create table so try this code,

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

And insert data using php so try this,

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I hope my answer is helpfull. If any query so comment please.

Comment: You might want to add an explanation on _why_ the OP should try this? What have you changed? How is it solving the issue?